# php loop array and update

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I wish to update the values in roomTotalPrice. However when I loop, it changes to just a variable.

Array I want to change:

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [12] => Array
                (
                    [num_rooms] => 2
                    [adults] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => 2
                        )

                    [prices] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 44.5
                            [1] => 44.5
                        )

                    [roomTotalPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 44.5
                            [1] => 44.5
                        )

                    [price] => 178
                    [supp] => 0
                )

        )
```

Code I am using:

```
//Total Room Price
foreach($iroom['roomTotalPrice'] as $irt){
    $s_rate[$iraid][$iroid]['roomTotalPrice'] = 100;
}



Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [12] => Array
                (
                    [num_rooms] => 2
                    [adults] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => 2
                        )

                    [prices] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 44.5
                            [1] => 44.5
                        )

                    [roomTotalPrice] => 100
                    [price] => 178
                    [supp] => 0
                )

        )
```

Comment: It'd be nice to see where the values from `$iraid` and `$iroid` come from. You're looping through the outer two arrays, presumably, where the indices of 10 and 12 are? And the whole array is `$s_rate`?

Comment: It would also be helpful to get some context on what you're trying to do, and perhaps an example of what you *want* the data to look like after your code runs.

Comment: yes $iraid and $iroid are the indices of 10 and 12,thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
foreach($iroom['roomTotalPrice'] as &$irt){
    $irt = 100;
}
```

Anyway this code is based on the fact that $iroom['roomTotalPrice'] loop on the right sub-array as you have written.

Comment: No sorry the roomTotalPrice is not changed

Comment: @KeithPower As I sayd, I'm assuming that the array on which you loop is the right one. Based on this, the code works as you can see here: http://codepad.org/x758PAxd (the values change)

Comment: Yes you are right, when I debug debug ($iroom) after the change is there. However I am trying to set it to the session. Like this code just after: $s_rate[$iraid][$iroid]['supp'] = $suptot; $this->Session->write('Res.Rate',$s_rate);

Comment: I have a form that I am tracking and I am using cakephp session read/write

Comment: @KeithPower Well...so this is definitively another question which, of course, you can ask to stackoverflow too.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just had to add this after the loop        $s_rate[$iraid][$iroid]['roomTotalPrice'] = $iroom['roomTotalPrice'];

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to make the sum for prices ?

$x[10][12][roomTotalPrice] =  array_sum($x[10][12][roomTotalPrice])

Comment: No, I just wish to change the 44.5 values to each 100

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the $iroom variable is the array in your first code sample, I believe you can use the following code to set all 'roomTotalPrice' entries to 100:

```
foreach ($iroom as $firstLevelIndex => $firstLevelArray) {
    foreach ($firstLevelArray as $secondLevelIndex => $secondLevelArray) {
        $iroom[$firstLevelIndex][$secondLevelIndex]['roomTotalPrice'] = 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what your want?

```
foreach ($iroom as $k1 => $v1) { // Loop outer array
  foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2) if (isset($v2['roomTotalPrice'])) { // Loop inner arrays and make sure they have a roomTotalPrice key
    foreach ($v2['roomTotalPrice'] as $k3 => $v3) { // Loop roomTotalPrice array
      $iroom[$k1][$k2]['roomTotalPrice'][$k3] = 100; // Change the values
    }
  }
}
```